# How do you make Execute do anything in Geany?

Tags: geany, ubuntu

I am trying out Geany for the first time. Compile and Build work fine (and indeed the commands are automatically detected), however I have been unable to make Execute do anything at all.

My setup:

- Create a new project
- Save a basic C hello world as hello-world.c

(I am using Kubutuntu 14.04.)

With no extra setup, pressing F9 or clicking Build -> Build correctly builds the executable. However, when I press F5 or click Build -> Execute, a terminal window appears with a `$` prompt, and nothing else.

I have tried going to Build -> Set Build Commands and changing the command next to Execute to various things, including "echo hi there", but the result is always the same: a `$` prompt, and nothing else.

How do I make F5 do anything?

Update: I have created VMs with clean installs of Ubuntu 14.04 and Kubuntu 14.04. Geany on Ubuntu works as expected, and F5 runs the program. On Kubuntu, I get the same issue I get on my laptop running Kubuntu 14.04. So it seems this is a Kubuntu specific problem.

Comment: Have you tried changing the options for program execution from the "build"-menu?

Comment: Yes - as I said in the question, I tried changing it to "echo hi there" and the same problem occurred.

Comment: Sorry, must've overlooked that. I cannot reproduce this issue; even the `echo hi there`-example works for me (Geany 1.24.1).

Comment: Which OS+version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

In Edit -> Preferences -> Tools, change the Terminal from

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "/bin/sh %c"
```

to

```
x-terminal-emulator -e /bin/sh %c
```

### Explanation

When you press Execute, Geany executes the terminal specified in Edit -> Preferences -> Tools, replacing %c with the Execute command set in Build -> Set Build Commands.

In Ubuntu, the default terminal emulator supports `-e` being passed a single parameter in quotes which contains an entire command line, and Execute works as expected. However, the default terminal emulator in Kubuntu is Konsole, which does not support this; it only supports using the rest of arguments after `-e` as a command line. When KDE attempted to implement it, [this bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=308553) was introduced so they reverted the change.

### Update

Konsole will support the terminal emulator parameters that Geany uses by default from KDE 4.14.2, so once that's out, this workaround will no longer be needed.

Answer (score 0):

This solution also works in Lubuntu 17.04.

In Geany
 Edit -> Preferences -> Tools, change the Terminal from
x-terminal-emulator -e "/bin/sh %c"
to
x-terminal-emulator -e /bin/sh %c