# Execute Command not working in Geany (Windows 10)

Tags: c++, windows, geany

I am really new to programming (actually trying to get this to work for my 1000 level intro C++ class) so I apologize for bad descriptions and lack of terminology.

I am having trouble getting a "Hello World" program to work on Geany.  I have followed the instructions here http://wiki.geany.org/howtos/win32/getting-started , pretty much to the letter. My program gets a successful message when I hit compile/build.  When I hit execute the terminal pops up but it is blank.

There is a flashing cursor in the spot where I would expect Hello World to be but instead it is blank, and I cannot type anything in the window.  From what I've researched I think it may be a similar problem from here [How do you make Execute do anything in Geany?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574359/how-do-you-make-execute-do-anything-in-geany) but searches on changing the terminal form to work for windows has not yielded any results.

In fact, I have not found much help for Geany on windows at all, so if there is a better set of software to use that is pretty basic I would be interested, I am only really attached to Geany because that is what we will be using in class (on a Linux operating system)

Thanks for the help!
John

Comment: Another possible cause is your anti-virus program eating your executable. See [Running my C++ code gives me a blank console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690697/running-my-c-code-gives-me-a-blank-console)

Comment: Do you have an executable at your folder?

Answer (score 0):

Avast Antivirus does, in fact, cause Geany to fail execution of the program. Windows 10 Pro 64-bit using Geany 1.26 full installer with MinGW. I just shut down shields for 10 mins and this allowed the program to execute.

Thanks.